# Looping through array of numbers for a specific id - sql

Tags: sql, arrays, json, sql-server, lateral-join

Here's my situation:

I can successfully manage to split an array of integers, but I've hit a roadblock where I am not sure how exactly to then assign each item from the list to the given `id`

```
DECLARE @position INT
DECLARE @arrayList varchar(8000)
DECLARE @len INT
DECLARE @value varchar(8000)

SET @arrayList = '1,2,3,4,5'

IF @arrayList NOT LIKE '%,'
BEGIN
    set @arrayList = @arrayList + ','
END

SET @position = 0
set @len = 0

WHILE CHARINDEX(',', @arrayList, @position+1)>0
BEGIN
    SET @len = CHARINDEX(',', @arrayList, @position+1) - @position
    SET @value = SUBSTRING(@arrayList, @position, @len)

    PRINT @value

    SET @position = CHARINDEX(',', @arrayList, @position+@len) +1
END
```

To paint a picture of what my issue is:

I need to loop through an `arrayList` for each `id` so that it can be displayed like the outcome below.

```
Table1
id  arrayList
23  [1,2,3]
47  [2,4,6]


Outcome
id  arrayList
23   1
23   2
23   3
47   2
47   4
47   6
```

Am I required to do some sort of while loop to check that the `id` is still `23` whilst looping, then move to the next `id` when the last number has been displayed from the array?

Comment: What is your SQL Server version?

Comment: SQL Server 2016

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use json functions?

```
select t1.id, v.value
from table1 t1
cross apply openjson(t.arraylist) v
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d671fab40018a896d624ce203a8e04f0)**:

```
select t.id, v.value 
from (values (23, '[1,2,3]'), (47, '[2,4,6]')) as t(id, arraylist)
cross apply openjson(t.arraylist) v
```

```
id | value
-: | :----
23 | 1    
23 | 2    
23 | 3    
47 | 2    
47 | 4    
47 | 6
```

Comment: this should be working but for some reason when I try it, its repeating the entire array for the id, instead of only displaying one number at a time

Comment: @user3396351: you might not be executing the query exactly as I provided. Are you able to reproduce the problem in the db fiddle I linked in my answer?

Comment: got it! I wasn't selecting the column `v` from the cross apply to get each individual value. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MS SQL Server 2016 and above you can use `STRING_SPLIT` for your solution.

> STRING_SPLIT is a table-valued function that splits a string into rows of substrings,
> based on a specified separator character.

Then you can write statement like this one:

```sql
WITH CleanArrayCTE AS
(
    SELECT id, REPLACE(REPLACE(arrayList, ']', ''), '[', '') as arrayList
    FROM Table1
)
SELECT id, value
FROM CleanArrayCTE CA
     CROSS APPLY (SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(CA.arrayList, ',')) r;
```

I have used `CTE` here only to remove close backets of array.